# I can't change my phone language to English (US) on WP 8.1

Tags: 8.1, cortana, language-setting

I want to enable Cortana outside of the US, but I can't change my phone language to US English. Does anybody have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: What phone do you have? As mentioned in [this answer](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/3539), some HTC phones have shipped without the US English language, making it impossible to enable Cortana.

Comment: What's stopping you from switching phone language to US English?

Answer (score 1):

simply go to Settings -> Region -> United States. Then restart your phone.
Again for example, if your phone language is India, download United States English.

Answer (score -1):

[As per this article](http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/windows-phone-81-tip-pin-cortana-your-start-screen):

> Cortana is technically only available in the United States during its initial beta period. However, if you change your region settings to United States, you should be able to access this feature. Microsoft tells me that doing so could impact Windows Phone Store access, but I've not heard of this actually happening to anyone.

**Changing the region**

Go to `Settings` → `region` → `United States`

**Windows Phone Store access**

If you must use Cortana at this point and find that your App Store isn't working as it normally does, you can still install the [apps you need via the WP website](http://www.windowsphone.com/store).

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. Merely changing the phone's region is not enough to enable Cortana, [changing the language is also required](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/3523/1401). And not being able to do that is the actual problem here that should be addressed (people might want to switch to US English for reasons other than Cortana).