# tried everything but cortana isnt there at all

Tags: cortana

Well I'm outside the US region and I changed my language region and all to US and still Cortana isn't there. Though I updated from Cyan to Denim, there is no Cortana. What to do?

Comment: Just a confirmation, have you read [this question and its answers?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3521/what-exactly-is-needed-to-activate-cortana?rq=1)

Comment: Where are you? which phone model do you have? which exact version number are you using? What do you see when you press the search key?

Answer (score -1):

You may need to reset your phone to defaults to change your region and make Cortana available, as it was not avail outside the U.S. However, the Windows Developer distribution now extends to regions outside the U.S.

[Win Phone 8.1 Dev Preview](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/devpreview)

Comment: The Lumia Denim update, which has started rolling out, is bringing Cortana to other regions

Comment: I have Lumia 720. When I press the search key, Bing opens but no Cortana. Tried everything. Restarted phone more than thrice! I need to reset it? Like a hard reset?